# My code doesn't properly change the TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Everything works with no errors, but in the xml, tvfinalgrade stays 0.0... Why isn't the double fin being displayed? I'm sure about what order the tvfin code lines should be written, but I'm assuming its not right.

```
public class GFActivity extends Activity {
public double fin;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.getfinal);

        double q1, q2, ex;
         EditText etq1, etq2, eteg;
         etq1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            try{
                q1 = Double.parseDouble(etq1.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                q1=0;
            }
         etq2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            try{
                q2 = Double.parseDouble(etq2.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                q2 = 0;
            }
         eteg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         try{
             ex = Double.parseDouble(eteg.getText().toString());
         } catch (NumberFormatException e){
             ex = 0;
         }
        fin = 0.4*q1+0.4*q2+0.2*ex;
            if(fin == (int)fin){
                System.out.println((int)fin);
            }
            else{
                fin = 0.01*((int)(fin*100));
                System.out.println(fin);
            } 
            Button solve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getfinbutton);
            solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView tvfin= TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfinalgrade);
                         tvfin.setText(fin+"");
                }
            });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the app, in the `onCreate()` you already parse the `EditText` content(which are empty, so you throw `NumberFormatException` and your `fin` variable ends up as `0`) and when you get to the part of setting the result(the user clicks the `Button`) you set the `fin` which is currently `0` to the `TextView`(the problem is that when the user clicks the `Button` you never get the **current** `EditText` content to do any calculation and the `fin` variable is the old value(`0`)). Move your calculation in the `onClick()` method:

```
Button solve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getfinbutton);
            solve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                   double q1, q2, ex;
         EditText etq1, etq2, eteg;
         etq1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            try{
                q1 = Double.parseDouble(etq1.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                q1=0;
            }
         etq2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            try{
                q2 = Double.parseDouble(etq2.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                q2 = 0;
            }
         eteg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
         try{
             ex = Double.parseDouble(eteg.getText().toString());
         } catch (NumberFormatException e){
             ex = 0;
         }
        fin = 0.4*q1+0.4*q2+0.2*ex;
            if(fin == (int)fin){
                System.out.println((int)fin);
            }
            else{
                fin = 0.01*((int)(fin*100));
                System.out.println(fin);
            } 
                    TextView tvfin= TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfinalgrade);
                         tvfin.setText(fin+"");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Just one other thing...instead of displaying 94.6, it displays 94.6000001. How can I fix this?

Comment: @JesusSqueegee Try this: `tvfin.setText(String.format( "%.2f", fin));`